# vCalender(vcs) to comma-seperated(csv) format convertion

Tags: conversion, format

I want my Mac iCal be able to read vcs format which my older windows outlook calender is on.

I thought about converting vcs calender format to csv format but I can't seem to find a website who does that.

Does anyone know how I could accomplish this?

Comment: **MAC ≠ Mac**. MAC = Media Access Control (address). Mac = Macintosh (computer). (I hate to nit-pick, but it really irks me).

Answer (score 0):

The [SyncWiz](http://3d2f.com/programs/73-408-syncwiz-for-outlook-download.shtml) add-in for Outlook sounds like it does what you want.

Comment: thanks but SyncWiz is for Windows users
do you know of an application for a mac?